# Get child nodes returning cannot loop error

Tags: java, jackrabbit, sling

I've got a pretty basic snippet of code that gets the currentNode of an object and looks through to get it's child nodes.  Except for some reason this isn't working and I can't figure out why. `getChildNodes()` is suppose to return an iterable list of children but all I'm getting is a: "Cannot loop with element of type **node** with collection of type **Iterable**

```
Node currentNode = resource.adaptTo(Node.class)
for (Node n : JcrUtils.getChildNodes(currentNode)){
//do something
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's probably means the collections returned is of `Iterable`s and not `Node`. Try `Iterable i` instead of `Node n`.

Comment: @BheshGurung thanks for the reply but I'm still getting an error except this time it says **cannot loop with element of type iterable with collection of type iterable**

Comment: @DelmonYoung The code you provided looks OK, I guess it's a different problem. Is it an compiler error or a runtime error? Please post the _exact_ error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Sling JSP script works for me. The sling:defineObjects tag provides currentNode.

```
<%@page import="javax.jcr.Node,org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils" session="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0"%>
<sling:defineObjects/>
<%
for (Node n : JcrUtils.getChildNodes(currentNode)){
  out.println(n.getPath());
}
%>
```